# Adding value to list within list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list that has been populated from a fetchXML query, but unfortunately it is returning a lot of events with duplicate titles. So as a solution i'm hoping to loop through each item in the list and, if the title is the same as the previous item, then I would like to add the values from item.YearId & item.Year to a list of years within the previously looped item.

```
var result = from p in fetchResults.Root.Elements("result") ... //etc

//Creating another list to contain desired results.
List<Event> eventDetails = new List<Event>();

//Create to store the previously looped title.
string previousTitle = string.Empty;

foreach (var item in result)
{
    if (item.Name == previousTitle)
    {
        //Not sure how to add item.yearId and item.Year to a Year
        //list inside the previously looped.
    }
    else
    {
        //otherwise add who item to eventDetails list.
        eventDetails.Add(item);
    }

    previousTitle = item.Name;
}
```

So, the Event class contains a Year list property that which consists of a guid (item.YearId) and an int (item.Year).

Hope that this makes sense.  Any examples would be great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this. I dont know what your event object looks like, but you should get the idea.

```
List<Event> eventDetails = new List<Event>();
Event lastEvent = null;

foreach (var item in result)
{
    if ((lastEvent != null) && (lastEvent.Name == item.Name))
    {
        lastEvent.AddYearAndYearId(item.Year, item.YearId);
        eventDetails[eventDetails.Count - 1] = lastEvent;
    }
    else
    {
        eventDetails.Add(item);
        lastEvent = item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies, because I don't think I made this clear in my question, but once you identified that the name was the same in the earlierEvent, how would you store that back into the eventDetails row that was just added.  It's just that I want to build up a list of Years in the first item that was stored in eventDetails (with each of the successive rows that share the same name).  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You can use something like: earlierEvent.AddYearAndYearId(item.Year, item.YearId); eventDetails[eventDetails.Count - 1] = earlierEvent; Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use grouping when fetching items from xml. Something like (just a sample, because I don't know how your xml looks):

```
var result = from p in fetchResults.Root.Elements("result")
             group p by p.Name into g
             select new Foo { 
                  Name = g.Key, 
                  Years = g.Select(x => (int)x.Element("year")).ToList()
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference to the previous item and use that reference so your code becomes

```
var result = from p in fetchResults.Root.Elements("result")... //etc

//Creating another list to contain desired results.
List<Event> eventDetails = new List<Event>();

//Create to store the previously looped title.
string previousTitle = string.Empty;

//Reference to previous event
Event previousEvent = null;

foreach (var item in result)
{
    if (item.Name == previousTitle && previousEvent != null)
    {
        //Add to the previous event
        previousEvent.yearList.Add(item.Year);
        previousEvent.yearIdList.Add(item.YearId);
    }
    else
    {
        //otherwise add who item to eventDetails list.
        eventDetails.Add(item);
    }

    previousTitle = item.Name;
    previousEvent = item;
}
```

Comment: And again, with your example, once i'd found a duplicate name, how would I build up the list of Years within the item that i'd just added to the eventDetails list?  Thanks.